# Parsing JSON - should be simple. What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, json, coinbase-php, coinbase-api

I'm trying to parse the Coinbase API to pull back the current price of Bitcoin. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kx5N/20/

```
var mtgoxAPI = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate";
$.getJSON(mtgoxAPI, function (json) {
      // Set the variables from the results array
      var price = json.amount;
      // Set the table td text
      $('#btc-price').text(price);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the "parsing"? It's done by jQuery automatically, so what I'm really asking is *what* is the problem? (Because it's not "parsing") - The error probably lies in failed access, such as "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" or other network/unexpected response issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) to sidestep the origin nonsense:

```
var mtgoxAPI = "https://coinbase.com/api/v1/prices/spot_rate?callback=?";

$.getJSON(mtgoxAPI, null, function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the results array
    var price = json.amount;


    // Set the table td text
    $('#btc-price').text(price);

});
```

works!  The coinbase API supports jsonp and jQuery can tell that you want jsonp when it sees

```
"?callback=?"
```

at the end of the URL.